# Dynamic Breadcrumb when selecting particular link in menu asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing dynamic binding using Menu control in asp.net works fine,

```
<asp:Menu ID="MenuCategory"  runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menustyle"
                StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="False">

</asp:Menu>
```

how to do for  dynamic breadcrumb when i am selecting a particular link in Menu control.. 
please help

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming problems. _Give me a sample code_ is not a good way to ask question in here.

Comment: i have added a code.. please tell me how to do dynamic breadcrumb for menu if u know pls